# If i already have an iPad only app in the store i'm allowed to make it universal in a future update?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store, universal

First of all, i already know how to make universal apps, my question is if having an iPad app in the store i'm allowed to add iPhone support in an update ( make it universal).

Also, if my iPad app doesn't has in-app purchases, i'm allowed to add new ones in an update ? ( i'm pretty sure the answer is yes but wanted to ask just in case)

Thanks for your orientation !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do both of those things. You'll have to sign additional contracts with Apple to offer in-app purchase, but that's done through iTunes Connect and doesn't affect the binary you submit.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely, your update will be accepted by Apple if it goes from iPad-only to universal.

Regarding the second point, yes you are of course allowed, but there is actually an issue that may force you to make a significant change before you can add in-app purchase to your existing app. If your app's bundle ID includes a wildcard, you will have to create a new one as such IDs are not compatible in with-app purchase (and also push notifications). See this other Stack Overflow question, [Converting wildcard bundle identifier to single ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912824/converting-wildcard-bundle-identifier-to-single-id), for details on this.